# do_action in API call

Tags: actions, wp-api

I have a woocommerce plugin and it provides an API url `?wc-api=myplugin`.

The plugin adds a new email also.

```php
function add_newstatus_woocommerce_email( $email_classes ) {
  require( 'emails/class-newstatus-email.php' );
  $email_classes['WC_Simplepay_Success_Email'] = new WC_Simplepay_Success_Email();
  return $email_classes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_newstatus_woocommerce_email' );
```

In `emails/class-wc-simplepay-success-email.php` I add an action in the constructor.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_newstatus', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
```

How can I use `do_action` to run this action from the plugin file? This does not seems to work. I guess it does not see that action.

```php
do_action('woocommerce_order_status_newstatus');
```

Comment: is the file `emails/class-wc-simplepay-success-email.php` definitely being included, and included in time before the action hook fires?

Comment: I think yes. The action is triggered when I do a change on the admin area, but not by the API call.

Comment: so if you've confirmed the current setup is working as-is for 1 scenario, but not for the other, then it's likely the file isn't being included during a rest api call. Are you providing the code that includes the file - why do you "think" it is being included?

Comment: here is the full code of the 2 files: https://controlc.com/35db2a48

Comment: @PaulG. the API call the same plugin file, so that is why I think it is included. The debugger also stops there if I add a breakpoint.

Comment: Actually re-reading, I don't fully understand the question "How can I use do_action to run this action from the plugin file? This does not seems to work. I guess it does not see that action". You need to clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve. Run what action? when? What's not working?

Comment: When I change the order's status at the admin page, the woocommerce_order_status_newstatus is triggered as excepted.
When I call the wc-api, I can programatically change the order's status, but it does not triggers this action. As  understand that is the way woocommerce works. So I have to programatically trigger that action. That is what I want with `do_action`